# How to properly handle file read/write errors in C?

Tags: python, c

I want to rewrite [yEnc](http://www.yenc.org/) code to make it compilable on Win32 with Visual Studio 2008.

The issue is that yEnc uses *unistd.h* (UNIX) functions *fcntl* to check if a file is readable or writable. It is of course not compatible with MS Visual Studio.

Here's what I want to be remove:

```
static Bool writable(FILE *file)
{
    int mode = fcntl(fileno(file),F_GETFL) & O_ACCMODE;
    return (mode == O_WRONLY) || (mode == O_RDWR);
}

static Bool readable(FILE *file)
{
    int mode = fcntl(fileno(file),F_GETFL) & O_ACCMODE;
    return (mode == O_RDONLY) || (mode == O_RDWR);
}
```

And here is how it is called:

```
FILE* infile = PyFile_AsFile(Py_infile);
FILE* outfile = PyFile_AsFile(Py_outfile);

if(!readable(infile) || !writable(outfile) ) {
    return PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "file objects not writeable/readable");
} 

/* File stuff including */    
fread(&read_buffer, 1, in_ind, infile);
if(ferror(infile) || ferror(outfile)) {
    return PyErr_Format(PyExc_IOError, "I/O Error while encoding");
}
fputc(CR, outfile);
fputc(LF, outfile);
fflush(outfile);
/* End of file stuff */
```

**Can someone help me converting this readable/writable check (with equivalent of try {} catch {} instead) ?**

I believe it is easier to handle errors on file read/write than trying to know if a Windows file is readable/writable, because there doesn't seem to be simple Windows equivalents to fcntl/F_GETFL.

The solution doesn't seem complicated but as I'm new to C and Python, I don't want to take the risk of making a buggy exception handler.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: C is like Yoda. Do or do not, there is no `try`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I think the following checks will be sufficient:

```
infile == NULL
outfile == NULL 
fread != read_count
fwrite != write_count
ferror
```

This should be sufficient. Moreover, the file have been opened in Python first and I presume this file open has been tested for exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert it just install windows POSIX.
http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    public string writepath;
    public string readpath;
    public string line;
    public List<Reciepient> reciepients = new List<Reciepient>();//linking my ist from my rec class
    public int index;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        writebutton.Enabled = false;//disables write button
    }

    public void createbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        writebutton.Enabled = true;//enables write button
        folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();//open folder browser
        writepath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath+ @"\test.txt";//generate path
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writepath);//open new sw
        textBox1.Text = writepath;//write path to textbox1
        sw.Close();//close my sw
    }

    public void readbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();//open my file browser
        readpath = openFileDialog1.FileName;//grabbing file name
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(readpath);//creating new sr
        textBox2.Text = readpath;//putting readpath in textbox2

        while(sr.Peek()!= -1)//will stop reading if noo more lines
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();//tells to read lines listed
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            /*if (line.Length > 0)
                continue;  messing up!!
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Line Cannot be Read");
        */
                string fname = line.Substring(0, 5);
                string lname = line.Substring(6, 6);
                int loccode = Int32.Parse(line.Substring(13, 1));
                int wcode = Int32.Parse(line.Substring(15, 1));
                double itemcost = double.Parse(line.Substring(17, 5));
                int acode = Int32.Parse(line.Substring(23, 1));

        Reciepient file = new Reciepient(fname, lname, loccode, wcode, itemcost,
        acode);
        reciepients.Add(file);//add to list

        }

        sr.Close();//closes streamreader
    }

    public void writebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writepath);
        Console.WriteLine(reciepients.Count);
        for (int index = 0; index < reciepients.Count(); index++)
        {
            Reciepient file = reciepients.ElementAt(index);
            sw.WriteLine(file.fname + " " + file.lname +" "+ "="+ file.totalcost);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
```